# STM32F030F4 dev on Linux

Tags: stm32

I ordered a few STM32F030F4 chips in a TSSOP 20 package, and some dip adapters.

I wired one up using a 8Mhz crystal and connected my st-link device to it via SWD.  st-link detects it correctly as an stm32f030 small device.

My problem is that I'm finding it very hard to figure out how to create a simple program for it that just blinks an LED.  Most GCC examples are for newer chips.  I even went so far as to boot into windows to try some of the IDEs available for it, but Ive had no luck.

Anyone have any suggestions for how I can get a simple GPIO program onto this chip to see if I wired it up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the STM32F030F4 [page](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1574/LN1826/PF258968) on ST's website and click on the Design Resources tab. Download Application Note AN4062 ("STM32F0DISCOVERY peripheral firmware examples") and its accompanying firmware package [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257885). The firmware package has 21 examples and preconfigured projects for 4 different IDEs, and includes a GPIO toggle example.

You might also want to read AN4080 ("Getting started with STM32F0xxx hardware development") if you're not sure about your hardware design.

Using one of the IDEs is probably the easiest way to get started. Some of them allow you to work on small (code size limited) projects without buying the license. The Design Resources page has links to many of the common ones out there.